# Error Applying Symbology to Shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, symbology, layers

I'm trying to apply symbology to my dataset after it is populated to the map display, but I am getting the following error. Have I placed the ApplySymbologyFromLayer code incorrectly?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\script\script.py", line 61, in <module>
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (Output_Feature_Class, in_symbology_layer)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6004, in ApplySymbologyFromLayer
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset C:/data/cluster_outlier_fieldname.shp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).
```

My script:

```
for fieldName in fieldList.split(';'):

    # Iterate
    Output_Feature_Class = "C:/data/cluster_outlier_" + fieldName + ".shp"
    outCluster = arcpy.ClustersOutliers_stats(inPointFeatures, fieldName, Output_Feature_Class,
                                              Conceptualization_of_Spatial_Relationships, Distance_Method,
                                              Standardization, Distance_Band_or_Threshold_Distance,
                                              Weights_Matrix_File, Apply_False_Discovery_Rate_FDR_Correction)

    # Add layers to map
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(Output_Feature_Class)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")

    # Symbolize
    in_symbology_layer = "C:/data/reference/design.lyr"
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (Output_Feature_Class, in_symbology_layer)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC() 
    del mxd, df, addLayer
```

Comment: Try arcpy.mapping.Layer() around your *.lyr file - I think that will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is a bit sloppy, but it gets the job done:

```
# Adjust layer symbology
out_layer = "shape.lyr"
layer = "shape.lyr"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Output_Feature_Class, out_layer)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(out_layer, layer, "ABSOLUTE")
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(out_layer, symbology)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(out_layer, layer, "ABSOLUTE")

# Add layer to map
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
```

I still find that the add layer to map code I'm using works in ArcMap v10.2, but not in v10.0. EDIT: Works in v10.0 with Service Pack 1 installed.